# Can I make Firefox use the user agent stored in the Registry?

Tags: firefox, user-agent

Is there a way to make Firefox get the user agent that is used in the Registry under "internet options"?

An option in `about:config` or so?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [User Agent Switcher](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/user-agent-switcher/), although it won't read the registry.